# Jpa Criteria Table alias

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, criteria-api

Hi i'm struggling to write the following query with criteria api:
"SELECT c.id,curr.name FROM Cargo c, Currency curr"

The problem is that both Cargo and Currency are aliased as c by criteria so the resulting jpql becomes "SELECT c.id,c.name FROM Cargo c, Currency c".

I don't know if it is because both entities start with C.
Is there a way to chage the table alias?

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query= criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();

Root<Cargo> cargo= query.from(Cargo.class);
Root<Currency> currency= query.from(Currency.class);
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: And `SELECT c.id, curr.name FROM Cargo c JOIN Currency curr`?

Comment: Inspect your mapping specifications for both entities and check that they aren't mapped on the same table.

Comment: They are mapped to different tables.Table names are different for both entities.

Comment: Entity names should not affect criteria api, as it is not usually translated into JPQL anyway (you didn't mention a provider though).  What is the SQL you are getting, and what results are you trying to get back?  "SELECT c.id,curr.name FROM Cargo c, Currency curr" gives back a cartesian product of the two tables, and doesn't seem all that useful, is this really what your application is after?

Comment: I'm using openjpa 2.2.2. This is the SQL i'm getting as stated in my original post: "SELECT c.id,c.name FROM Cargo c, Currency c". The point is that the TWO entities are aliased as "c".

Comment: When i use one entity there is no problem.Two or more entities that start with different letters no problem.But when they start with the same letter as in my post then oops!.Maybe the alias is chosen from the first letters of the entities names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing the part where you specify what you want selected.  "SELECT c.id,curr.name FROM Cargo c, Currency curr"
would likely translate to something like:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query= criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();

Root<Cargo> cargo= query.from(Cargo.class);
Root<Currency> currency= query.from(Currency.class);

query.multiselect(cargo.get("id"), currency.get("name"));
Query query = em.createQuery(cq);
List<Tuple> results = query.getResultList();
```

There is an example here using only one table:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#Tuple_Queries

Comment: When i use one entity there is no problem.Two or more entities that start with different letters no problem.But when they start with the same letter as in my post then oops!.Maybe the alias is chosen from the first letters of the entities names.

Comment: Maybe.  Did you try fixing the query as suggested and do you get the same result?  What occurs with the JPQL query?

Comment: Yes I did.got same result.I can confirm that the table alias is chosen from first letter of entity name.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of debugging, i found out that the actual jpql that is executed is different from the one that is displayed in my ide(eclipse).
The aliases were ok.I think i was a bit deceived by the ide.
Thanks all for your attention.